# How do i push after changing the branch using gitbash

Tags: git, gitlab, branch, git-branch, git-bash

When i try to change my branch and push the code to new branch a error is thrown. How to overcome this type of error

![REJECTED]
error: failed to push some refs to 'some link'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Did you read the information suggested? Research the error message? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22Updates+were+rejected+because+the+remote+contains+work%22

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+remote+contains+work+that+you+do+not+have+locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution Arvind :
Make sure whether you copied the right path from either GitHub or Bitbucket [Click here for more info](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-push#:~:text=The%20git%20push%20command%20is,exports%20commits%20to%20remote%20branches.)

Comment: thanks for the solution

Comment: Before answering the question, confirm if the question is already present. If it's present, then point to that question and close the question.